# Microsoft HTTPAPI/2.0 use Port 80 – Cannot Start WAMP Apache

Tags: wamp, httpapi

Microsoft HTTPAPI/2.0 use Port 80 – Cannot Start WAMP Apache.

how can i stop microsoft httpapi/2.0 ?

Answer (score 7):

I've just ran into this myself... it means something else is using port 80, could be anything from IIS, SQL Reporting Services, even Skype can be found to use port 80. Also check if you have Web Platform Installer installed which can use port 80.

Quick-fix would be to change the apache port in WAMP.

Comment: Yeah! 
1. Just edit the httpd.conf; 
2. replace the line "Listen 80" to another port, "Listen 8888", for example.
3. So the http://localhost will turn http://localhost:8888

:) Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Brock, for me SQL Reporting Services was the culprit!

Comment: The OP already discovered this. OP needs to know how to change the port for `Microsoft HTTPDAPI/2.0`.